# CoImpersonateClient and Worker Threads

Tags: windows, security, com, service

I have an existing COM service which runs under the local system account as a service.
It's sole purpose when a client connects is to run a third party function with impersonation. i.e. something like;

```
    void service_client()
    {
        CoImpersonateClient();
        tfp(); //third_party_function
        ...
    }
```

This has all worked well for years but now tfp() has changed in that whilst remaining synchronous overall it internally spawns worker threads which pick up the identity of local system account instead of the impersonated client which causes the function to fail.

Is there a way of working around this, given that I can't modify tfp()

Thanks.

Comment: Impersonation is thread-specific.  Work with the vendor, you can't be the only one having this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the vendor is of no help, it's not how they want to see their product used. So far my only solution is to package tfp() into an exe and CreateProcessAsUser() and use pipes for cross-process communication but this is going to kill performance.